# How to give multiple example values for same object using swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have created one Model class(Product),it contains two feilds name and value.
I would like to give swagger default values for Product model. I was able to do it with the help of @ApiModelProperty annotation and it's working fine. 
But my actual requirement is to give multiple values for same object something like this

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "X",
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "Y",
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "Z",
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "A",
      "value": "01"
    }
  ]
}
```

this default model I am trying to create for HTTP POST request how can I achieve this with swagger2 and springboot

Comment: That called value of ArrayList<Product> !

Comment: @sovannarithcheav  Yes List< Product>

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the filed with `datatype="List"`

```
public class MyClass {
....
@ApiModelProperty(datatype="List", example = "'['{'name': 'X','value': '100'}']")
private List< Product> products;
....
}
```

**Edit**

```
public class MyClass {
....
@ApiModelProperty(value = "{\n'name':'X',\n'value':'100'\n},\n{\n'name':'Y',\n'value':'100'\n}")
private List< Product> products;
....
}
```

Comment: I have tried above given code and i am getting out put as a Single string. It's not looks like a request body and if i have more objects, it will very difficult to understand what values we have given. How can we format it like a proper request body

Comment: @NIKHILKA Could you try with this `@ApiModelProperty(datatype="List", example = "[{'name': 'X','value': '100'}]")`

Comment: I am getting like this    {
  "Products": "[{'name': 'X','value': '100'},{'name': 'Y','value': '101'},{'name': 'Z','value': '102'}]"
}

Comment: If i add more objects it will be very difficult to validate values or update values . Hope you understand my problem

Comment: I just found we use key `value`
`    @ApiModelProperty(value = "{\n'name':'X',\n'value':'100'\n},\n{\n'name':'Y',\n'value':'100'\n}")`

Comment: {
  "products": "{\n'name':'X',\n'value':'100'\n},\n{\n'name':'Y',\n'value':'100'\n}"
}

Comment: This is how I am getting response. Is there any way to use @ApiModelProperty for multiple objects ?

Comment: @NIKHILKA Multiple objects??

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this format using  @ApiModelProperty ?

Comment: `public class MyClass {
....
@ApiModelProperty(value = "{\n'name':'X',\n'value':'100'\n},\n{\n'name':'Y',\n'value':'100'\n}")
private List< Product> products;

@ApiModelProperty(value = "Sovannarith")
private String name;
....
}`

Comment: Still it's coming as single line, not in json format

Comment: If i use @ApiModelProperty inside product class something like this //    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Name of the product.",example = "X")
    private String name;  I am getting exactly like a json object. But problem with this approach i can't give more values for same property.If i give it will not appear as different product object

Comment: @jaco0646  any idea about this issue